# Python Scipy Optimize not recongnising Lambdas while using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, scipy

While trying to create an optimisation algorithm for work, i found a particular problem:

Here is some basic information about the code :

**LZ is a nestedlist.**

**M is a numpy array converted from the nestedlist.**

here is the code :

```
for i in range(len(LZ)):
    for j in range(len(LZ[i])):
        constraints1 = lambda MA, i=i,j=j: MAXQ - abs(M[i][j]-MA[i][j])
        print(M[i][j])
        if j <len(LZ[i])-1:
            constraints2 = lambda MA, i=i,j=j: PENTEMAX +((MA[i][j]-MA[i][j+1])/LL[i][j])
            constraints3 = lambda MA, i=i,j=j: PENTEMAX - ((MA[i][j]-MA[i][j+1])/LL[i][j])
        cons.append({'type' : 'ineq','fun' : constraints1})
        cons.append({'type' : 'ineq','fun' : constraints2})
        cons.append({'type' : 'ineq','fun' : constraints3})
x0 = M
sol = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons)
```

I run the code, and here is what i get :
it prints the M[i][j] just fine, the printing is long so i didnt copy it here :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Opti Assainissement/VOIRIE5.py", line 118, in <module>
    sol = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 611, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 315, in _minimize_slsqp
    for c in cons['ineq']]))
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
    for c in cons['ineq']]))
  File "D:/Opti Assainissement/VOIRIE5.py", line 101, in <lambda>
    constraints1 = lambda MA, i=i,j=j: cdt(MA,i,j)
  File "D:/Opti Assainissement/VOIRIE5.py", line 98, in cdt
    return MAXQ - abs(M[i][j]-MA[i][j])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

My first guess was that SciPy doesnt recognise MA as an array, but i can't know if it's related to SciPy or the lambda construction or to my lack of knowledge in the matter. I'll be glad to get somehelp from the community !

Comment: `i` and `j` don't have the actual value when the lambda functions are *called*, compared to when they are constructed. When the lambda functions are used in the solver, they have their last calculated values, which is the limit in their respective for loops.

Comment: You should not make your lambdas dependent on i and j

Comment: @9769953, these `lambda` definitions bind the `i` and `j` values at definition time by making them the default values of the keyword parameters.  That should avoid the late-binding problem.

Comment: @ElhassaniAmine, it would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In the meantime: it looks like you expect the constraint functions to be passed a two-dimensional array. That is not how `minimize` works.  It expects the objective function and the constraint functions to be functions of a *one-dimensional* array.  You'll have to implement your code with `MA` flattened to a 1-d array.

Comment: @9769953 i know that's why i used : lambda MA,i=i,j=j : .....
the i=i / j=j passes the argument to the functions in the time it is called not the end value of the loop.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : M.shape returns the dimensions of the array in the form of tuple, example : M  = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]]), M.shape prints (2,2).

Thank you for your last implementation i'll try the flattening solution.

Comment: If you want to use those specific values of i and j, you need to use a closure that returns the constraint function.